# Making images display in a row from top to bottom

Tags: html, css, image, display

i have this collection of pictures that i want to display in a column.

```
    <div class="row">

    <img src="image1" alt="">
    <img src="image2" alt="">
    <img src="image3" alt="">

    </div>
```

right now i have this and all 3 images just display side by side by side and what i want is to display the images from top top to bottom like a column. i know i have to do something with the row class in css i just don't know what so i hope someone can help me out here :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.row {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
}
```

Comment: Or you can just declare "display: grid" for class .row

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can display images vertically like this :

```
.row img {
display: block;
}
```